# How to include and use DefinePlugin in webpack config?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

Hi there i am trying to use the define plugin so i can update the version number to make sure my JS refreshes after releasing a new build.  I can't seem to get DefinePlugin to work properly though.  I see it in the folder webpack and i'm trying to follow the documentation but i get errors that it isn't found.  Here is my config:

```
const path = require('path'),
settings = require('./settings');

const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');


module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'scrollerbundled': [settings.themeLocation + "js/scroller.js"],
    'mapbundled': [settings.themeLocation + "js/shopmap.js"],
    'sculptor': [settings.themeLocation + "js/sculptor.js"]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, settings.themeLocation + "js-dist"),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true),
    VERSION: JSON.stringify('5fa3b9'),
  })]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({ 
            uglifyOptions: {
                mangle: true,
                output: {
                    comments: false
                }
            }
       })]
  },
  mode: 'production'
}
```

Comment: In my case, I used `'process.env.VARIABLE_NAME'` instead of just normal variables and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
 "parser": "babel-eslint",
 "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/react"
 ],
 "plugins": ["react", "import", "prettier"],
 "env": {
   "browser": true
 },
 "settings": {
 "import/resolver": {
  "webpack": {
    "config": "webpack.dev.js"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

That's my eslintrc. This is for use absolute imports created in your webpack config with the modules alias. You need to install [eslint-import-resolver-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-webpack)

Comment: Check question again, is there anything about eslint config?

Answer (score 4):

I Have "webpack": "^4.28.4" and define in webpack config

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
 PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(true),
});
```

if you console that variables, you don't find it. I use in conditional

```
if (PRODUCTION) {
 //do stuff
}
```

Another case is to set globals variables in a object and share with webpack.

here is an example

```
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        CONFIG: path.resolve(__dirname, './CONSTS.js')
        }),
        // the path is src/CONST.JS
```

In the eslintrc file you can add that variables to avoid import errors.

```
    "settings": {
     "import/resolver": {
      "webpack": {
       "config": "webpack.dev.js"
      }
     }
    }
```

then in any file you can use import {value} from 'CONFIG'

Comment: where is it that you are setting "settings": {
     "import/resolver": {
      "webpack": {
       "config": "webpack.dev.js"
      }
     }
    }?  Could you show your entire config file so i can see under which sections to put the plugin and config?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using laravel mix, you can place that `new webpack.DefinePlugin` code into the `plugins` array of your `.webpackConfig` block:

webpack.mix.js:

```
mix
.webpackConfig({
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'sass': path.resolve('resources/sass'),
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'window.Quill': 'quill',     // <--------------------- this right here
        __VERSION__: JSON.stringify('12345')
        })
    ]
})
.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.copy([
    'resources/fonts/*',
], 'public/fonts');
```

By extrapolation, that means you can also add this code to the similar block in your regular (not laravel mix) webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

Install `devtools` globally

```
npm install -g @vue/devtools
```

... and try again.

If уоu have any issues try following the official [instructions](https://devtools.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html).